# 400 Error when requesting a token from Discord API

Tags: node.js, discord, fetch, discord.js, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to create a login process with Discord's API. Per the documentation I'm suppose to use the `code` returned on the callback URL to make another call to receive the access token. I've followed the instructions [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2). However, I keep receiving a `400` error when making the call.

Any help on what I need to correct?

```
let options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + discordInfo.client_id + ":" + discordInfo.client_secret,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data: {
    'client_id': discordInfo.client_id,
    'client_secret': discordInfo.client_secret,
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': req.query.code,
    'redirect_uri': discordInfo.callbackUrl,
    'scope': 'identify email'
  }
}

let discord_data = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', options).then((response) => {
  if (response.status >= 400) {
    throw new Error("Bad response from server");
  }
  return response.json();
}).then((response) => {
  console.log('Discord Response', response);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

After further research, I discovered the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gg40nfS0pTU) which helped me out.

Here is the working code:

```
let options = {
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    'client_id': discordInfo.client_id,
    'client_secret': discordInfo.client_secret,
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'code': req.query.code,
    'redirect_uri': discordInfo.callbackUrl,
    'scope': 'identify email'
  })
}

let discord_data = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', options).then((response) => {
  return response.json();
}).then((response) => {
  return response;
});
```